# Not able to call any method from contract in react js app (Solidity, Ganache, Truffle & React)

Tags: solidity, truffle, metamask, ganache, react

Not able to call any method from contract in react-js app, but if I print contracts in console, I can see all the methods that I've define in contract.

**I have also upload this project to git here is the [link](https://github.com/iammanpreetbhullar/Crypto-Solidity-react-ganache.git)**

below is the code inside react

**App.js --**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3';
import './App.css';
import { CryptoFirst_ABI, CryptoFirst_ADDRESS } from './config'

function App() {

const [account, setAccount] = useState();
const [contractList, setContractList] = useState();
const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
async function load() {
  const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 
'http://localhost:7545')
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
  setAccount(accounts[0]);
  const addr = 'metamask-account-address';
  const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(addr)
  console.log(balance)
  const contracts = new web3.eth.Contract(CryptoFirst_ABI, 
CryptoFirst_ADDRESS)
  setContractList(contracts)
  const counter = await contracts.methods.count().call()
  for (var i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
    const contact = await contracts.methods.contacts[i].call();
    setContacts((contacts) => [...contacts, contact]);
  }
}
load();
}, [])

return (
<div className="App">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>Your account is: {account}</p>
  <ul>
    {
      Object.keys(contacts).map((contact, index) => (
        <li key={`${contacts[index].name}-${index}`}>
          <h4>{contacts[index].name}</h4>
          <span><b>Phone: </b>{contacts[index].phone}</span>
        </li>
      ))
    }
  </ul>
</div>
);
}
export default App;
```

**contract file --**

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract CryptoFirst {
uint public count = 0;

struct Contact {
    uint id;
    string name;
    string phone;
}

constructor() {
    createContact("myname", "phone-number");
}

mapping(uint256 => Contact) public contacts;

event ContactCreated(uint id, string name, string phone);

function createContact(string memory _name, string memory _phone) 
public {
    count ++;
    contacts[count] = Contact(count, _name, _phone);
    emit ContactCreated(count, _name, _phone);
}

function myFunction() public pure returns(uint256 myNumber, string 
memory myString) {
    return (23456, "Hello!%");
}
}
```

**config.js in react ----**

```
export const CryptoFirst_ADDRESS = "";
export const CryptoFirst_ABI = [
{
"inputs": [],
"stateMutability": "nonpayable",
"type": "constructor"
},
{
"anonymous": false,
"inputs": [
  {
    "indexed": false,
    "internalType": "uint256",
    "name": "id",
    "type": "uint256"
  },
  {
    "indexed": false,
    "internalType": "string",
    "name": "name",
    "type": "string"
  },
  {
    "indexed": false,
    "internalType": "string",
    "name": "phone",
    "type": "string"
  }
],
"name": "ContactCreated",
"type": "event"
},
{
"inputs": [
  {
    "internalType": "uint256",
    "name": "",
    "type": "uint256"
  }
],
"name": "contacts",
"outputs": [
  {
    "internalType": "uint256",
    "name": "id",
    "type": "uint256"
  },
  {
    "internalType": "string",
    "name": "name",
    "type": "string"
  },
  {
    "internalType": "string",
    "name": "phone",
    "type": "string"
  }
],
"stateMutability": "view",
"type": "function",
"constant": true
},
{
"inputs": [],
"name": "count",
"outputs": [
  {
    "internalType": "uint256",
    "name": "",
    "type": "uint256"
  }
],
"stateMutability": "view",
"type": "function",
"constant": true
},
{
"inputs": [
  {
    "internalType": "string",
    "name": "_name",
    "type": "string"
  },
  {
    "internalType": "string",
    "name": "_phone",
    "type": "string"
  }
],
"name": "createContact",
"outputs": [],
"stateMutability": "nonpayable",
"type": "function"
},
{
"inputs": [],
"name": "myFunction",
"outputs": [
  {
    "internalType": "uint256",
    "name": "myNumber",
    "type": "uint256"
  },
  {
    "internalType": "string",
    "name": "myString",
    "type": "string"
  }
],
"stateMutability": "pure",
"type": "function",
"constant": true
}
];
```

**package.json content --**

```
{
"name": "crypto-first",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
"@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
"ethers": "^5.5.3",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-bootstrap": "^2.1.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"solc": "^0.8.11",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.3",
"web3": "^1.6.1"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": [
  "react-app",
  "react-app/jest"
]
},
"browserslist": {
"production": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
],
"development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
]
}
}
```

**Console is showing this: -**

[image: console]

Comment: That error usually mean the address or the abi aren't correct (the call returns a value that web3 isn't expecting, e.g empty, null, undefined). Can you check if you are connecting to the right network? An issue in the contract is this call `contracts.methods.contacts[i].call()` since `contacts` is a mapping the correct call is `contracts.methods.contacts(i).call()` with `()` instead of `[]`.

Comment: @Ismael thanks for the reply.
I migrate the contract using "truffle migrate --reset" and then I copy the ABI & address  from "/build/contracts/cryptoFirst.json" and paste it inside "config.js" file in react project, before running "npm start".
I have tried calling the method like `contracts.methods.contacts(i).call()` but got the same results and I can see all the methods of contract by using `console.log(await contracts.methods)`

Comment: **this is the console result** 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcO51.png

Comment: The object `contracts` is built from the abi so it will always show the methods defined there. There's no way for web3 to validate the address contains a contract and those methods are defined there. Are you sure you are connected to the correct blockchain? e.g ganache, rinkeby, or if using metamask is it connected to the right blockchain?

Comment: yes I am using ganache and inside ganache I am using server address - **127.0.0.1:7545" and network Id "5777"** but  metamask is connected to rinkbey, when I try to connect metamask with ganache by adding network it give the error about chain Id is 1337 instead of 5777 **this is the network already added in metamask** https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K4TG.png but when I try to add network it gives this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AD9F.png

Comment: To force the connection to the ganache change web3 instantiation to `Web3('http://localhost:7545')`, or fix the Metamask-ganache connection (that was asked previously so search for the answer).

Comment: @Ismael Its working now, thankyou very much for your help...

Comment: **the working project is on github -- you can find the link to the project at the top of this question**